# Working on a design that requires a specific kind of physical switch

Tags: switches, component-selection

The switch my design needs behaves like the picture below. The user would slide the switch to the right to activate it and the switch would return to the left automatically, I assume by some kind of spring-action. I'm having trouble actually finding a switch like this on Digikey or Mouser and I think I'm using the wrong keywords. Does anyone know the right keywords?

[image]

Comment: VTC this as it is a request for recommendations for a specific product (i.e. "shopping question"). Please be aware that specialty switches such as you describe are almost always custom designed with the actuator and spring factored into the packaging design of the product. The custom actuator is designed such that it mechanically interfaces with some type of standard switch be that a slide switch, micro switch or some other type.

Comment: This wasn't "seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them". There was a specific question: "What is this thing called and how do I describe it to a hopeful seller?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need a momentary action switch. The momentary action is encased in parenthesis so a double throw momentary comes in two configurations:   on-on-(on) and on-off-(on) switch

So if you search for a switch type, you would just type:  on-on-(on) in the search box to get those type of switches.

Comment: The configuration advice is misleading. The OP needs the key terms "momentary" and "slide".

Answer (score 1):

The search phrase "momentary slide switch" brings them up.  Lots to choose from at Mouser and Digi-Key.

[Example.](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/switches/slide-switches/213?k=momentary&k=&pkeyword=momentary&sv=0&pv235=14&pv235=5&sf=0&FV=ffe000d5&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25)